# pdo counting hardcoded IN clause as needing parameters

Tags: php, pdo

Check out the following:

```
$idPlaceholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$query = $db->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM sometable
    WHERE
      id IN(' . $idPlaceholders . ')
      AND status IN ("open", "reopened")
');
$query->execute($ids);
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> PHP warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

**If I remove the `AND status IN (...)` clause, it runs fine.** Am I doing something wrong? I was under the impression that *hardcoded values are ignored by PDO*.

Note, I have triple-checked and the number of "?" match the number of ids.

The `$ids` array is an indexed array (here is the var_dump):

```
array 3
    0 => int 23
    1 => int 45
    2 => int 67
```

The rendered query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE
  id IN (?,?,?)
  AND status IN ("open", "reopened")
```

Comment: Can you show the sql as gets created after the `$idPlaceholders` variable is substituded?

Comment: Might be a problem with indexes in your $ids. Show us the dump please. Or try applying `sort()` to them before `execute()`.

Comment: Change error reporting from warning to exception, follow the back trace and find the right query that is causing this error

Comment: A shot in the dark, but could you try and change double quotes around "open" and "reopened" to single quotes? (Might require you to wrap your query string in double quotes instead.)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have debugged the poo out of this. The hardcoded "status IN (...)" clause is the problem. If I remove it, the query runs fine.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov tried that, but unfortunately, same issue

Comment: All looks legit, then. Could you show us the table structure and some sample data, perhaps? Would be interesting to try and replicate it locally.

Comment: Ugh, are you kidding me! Sorry to waste everyone's time. Turns out, this application I'm working on is extending PDO and overriding `execute`. Why!? Why!? Why!? Why!? Why!? Apologies to @YourCommonSense, I did not follow the backtrace far enough as you had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this so as to remove it from the open question lists. Not deleting as I don't want to get banned.

The application I am using extends PDO and adds a feature to auto-expand a placeholder within an IN clause (e.g. `IN (:ids)`). Turns out, it breaks if you do it the way I outlined in my question.

Answer (score -2):

can you try if this will work?

```
$idPlaceholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$query = $db->prepare('
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE
  id IN(' . $idPlaceholders . ')
  AND status IN (?, ?)
');
$ids[]="open";
$ids[]="reopened";
$query->execute($ids);
```

Comment: It will most probably work, but it doesn't answer OP's question. He should be able to hardcode values into his query as well.